# C# Random isn't producing a random result

Tags: c#, class, random

I am working on a project for class. It is my first time coding in C# and have ran into an issue. I need to randomly generate a number (1,2, or 3) for a rock paper scissors game but the program keeps outputting 3 and not a random number. Here is my code. Any suggestions on why this is occurring?

```
using System;
class elevator{
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        string response;

        // Create an instance of the random class
        Random random = new Random();

        // Return a random non negative interger. Max is set to 4 as it is exclusive and will set the true max to 3.
        int compChoice = random.Next(1, 4); 


        Console.Write("Do you want to play Rock, Paper, Scissors? ");
        response = Console.ReadLine();
        response = response.ToUpper();


        while(response == "YES"){

            // If statements displaying auto generated play for first player.
            if(compChoice == 1){
                Console.WriteLine("First player <computer> Selection - Rock");
            }
            if(compChoice == 2){
                Console.WriteLine("First player <computer> Selection - Paper");
            }
            if(compChoice == 3){
                Console.WriteLine("First player <computer> Selection - Scissors");
            }

            // Allow user to make selection
            Console.Write("Second Player Selection - <Type 1,2, or 3. Rock = 1, Paper = 2, or Scissors = 3>: ");
                int secondPlayer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // Determine Winner
            if (secondPlayer == 1 & compChoice == 1) {
                Console.WriteLine("You both chose rock!");
            }
            if (secondPlayer == 1 & compChoice == 2) {
                Console.WriteLine("Player two wins! Paper covers rock.");
            }
            if (secondPlayer == 1 & compChoice == 3) {
                Console.WriteLine("Player one wins! Rock smashes scissors.");
            }
            if (secondPlayer == 2 & compChoice == 1) {
                Console.WriteLine("Player one wins! Paper covers rock.");
            }
            if (secondPlayer == 2 & compChoice == 2) {
                Console.WriteLine("You both chose paper!");
            }
            if (secondPlayer == 2 & compChoice == 3) {
                Console.WriteLine("Player two wins! Scissors cut paper.");
            }           
            if (secondPlayer == 3 & compChoice == 1) {
                Console.WriteLine("Player two wins! Rock smashes scissors.");
            }
            if (secondPlayer == 3 & compChoice == 2) {
                Console.WriteLine("Player one wins! Scissors cut paper.");
            }
            if (secondPlayer == 3 & compChoice == 3) {
                Console.WriteLine("You both chose scissors!");
            }

            // Ask user if they want to play another round
            Console.Write("Do you want to play Rock, Paper, Scissors? ");
            response = Console.ReadLine();
            // Convert response to all caps
            response = response.ToUpper();

        }
    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to move the number generation into your loop. Also, `Random` isn't random as per specification; please read it. Try to initialize it differently. In your case this would do: `Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Milliseconds);`

Comment: _Random() isn't random as per specification; please read it._ Wise words you should follow yourself..

Comment: `Random` generates pseudo-random numbers, not random numbers. It uses statistics to calculate a "random" number; therefore, it is not random. It appears to be random when seeded with different numbers. Anyway, irrelevant for this question and just a side note. The issue related to the question is a code issue as per @Alex' answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the random number generation in the loop :

```
while (response == "YES") {
    int compChoice = random.Next(1, 4);
```

Otherwise, it will generate the number once and take that one all the time

See `random.Next` as "Random, can I get the next random number", as you did it with the `Console.ReadLine()` for the second player